# Getting a string from a view,saving it and overwriting data in the previous view

Tags: iphone

I am doing a calendar event app. I have a function of editing the event.  When the function is selected, the already added info will be shown. respectively, it will be clicked for editing.
So, i want to change the event name in this case. When clicked, it will go the the next view to show a table of list of events i can choose. What i want to do is, once clicked on a cell, i want my program to the main editing view and also the event name now must be changed to the new name i selected. Is this possible? All the information are read from memory. So, when i want to change the memory directly using 
[[mainDelegate.personArray objectAtindex:i]eventname]= Changedname;
it says Lvalue required as left method of operand.. so is there any other way...Fast help is needed

Answer (score 0):

eventName is a getter not a mutator. What you want to do is this:

```
[[mainDelegate.personArray objectAtindex:i] setEventName:changedName]
```

Comment: if i use this code can it overwrite the event name i already saved.. when i rerun the app, the eventname still remains the old one